# How to do hand draw on existing image in xamarin forms

Tags: canvas, xamarin.forms, drawing, skiasharp

I working on Xamarin forms application. I got a requirement that I need to hand draw on the existing image and to save it. Can you please say how to do it.

Better if any example program.

For more details, please refer this link https://www.dropbox.com/s/lbgz6igxonuev90/IMG-1113.TRIM.MOV?dl=0 I have uploaded the video that demonstrates my requirement.

Note: I need to hand draw on the existing image.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with Skisharp, [tutorial here](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/bitmaps/drawing) explains how to modify an existing image.

You can also use SyncFusion [Image Editor Control for Xamarin.Forms](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/xamarin/image-editor)